# How to access content page controls from master page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

it is very easy to access master page control from content page like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // content page load event
    DropDownList thisDropDown = this.Master.FindControl("someDropDown") as DropDownList;
    userLabel.Text = thisDropDown.SelectedValue;
}
```

but how could i access controls of content page from master page. suppose a textbox there in content page and one button is there in master page. i want that when i will click on master page button then i want to show the text of textbox in the content page in the label of master page. how to achieve it. please help me with code sample. thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In master page button click event should access page contents by:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("TextBox1");
    if (TextBox1 != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: So stupid that this much code is required... I'm not attributing that to your answer, but to the ASP.net model

Comment: Crashing the party; not sure the "thorough" comments are meant for the "error handling" or what, but in that case I would advise that you actually not check the result of `FindControl`.  If you're not doing anything fancy, it's very likely that you'd much rather want to get an exception to signal the error, rather than silently doing nothing. Even better: Use an assertion, and don't make the check in production code. If you still manage to somehow ship a project where an expected control is missing, prefer to redirect the user to a friendly error page, and fix your release process.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but I believe you can do so by using the ContentPlaceHolder as a reference:

```
Control control = this.myContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("ContentPageControlID");
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it even better to use event raise from Master page and catch this event in contenet page for changing some contenet on this page, for instance. The main advantage is  reusability. In future you may want to change content on other content page from the Master page and in this case you should only add event handler to this content page without changing code on master page. Within such approach you needn't hardcode control name from some content page. And moreover you shouldn't add dependency for some content's control at all.

A sample of implementation you can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MasterContentInteraction.aspx), for example.

Answer (score 1):

you should look for contentplaceholder from master page then contentplaceholder in child of the master page

```
this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("controlAFromPage");
```

Comment: I got relieved...masterpages, woff! and then this long finding path!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find control by using this:

```
ContentPlaceHolder contentPage = Page.MasterPage.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
Label lblHead =(Label)contentPage.FindControl("lblHeading");
Response.Write(lblHead.Text);
```

Source:
http://xpode.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ArticleId=629

Answer (score 0):

C# code within Site.Master:

```
<div>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Code within Site.Master.cs:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        ToolkitScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(this.MainContent.FindControl("btnOnDefaultPage"));            
    }
}
```

This is an example how a client control on the Default.aspx is referenced from a Site.Master.cs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("DivContainer_MyProfile").Visible = True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
  When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to WHY your answer is the one.