# cannot access hiddenfield value in masterpage on page_load event from child page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, webforms

I'm trying to access a hiddenfield value from my masterpage that is set in my child aspx page, but cannot access it the masterpage codebehind page_load event.

Child aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadStyleSheetManager>
<div class="center_content">
    <div style="text-align: left">
        <h2>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: left">
        <uc1:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    &nbsp;</div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hid1" runat="server" Value="Satellite Availability % Report" />
```

Master page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Style="text-align: right; font-size: xx-large; color: #808080"></asp:Label>
```

Master page code behind: This is where I want to set the text value of the report from the child page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField hid1 = (HiddenField)MainContent.FindControl("MainContent_hid1");
    if (hid1 != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = hid1.Value;
    }        }
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$hdnRptTitle" id="MainContent_hdnRptTitle" value="Satellite Availability % Report" />
```

There is no intellisense for the hdnRptTitle variable.

How can I get this to work? It seems simple enough, but don't know why it not working...

Comment: Why do you think that you can access a control in a content-page of a master-page? A `MasterPage` is used for multiple pages, why do you want to hardlink it with a specific page, it won't work anymore without it. If the `HiddenField` is essential for the operation of the master you should declare it there.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? For every child page, there is a different rpt title which needs to show up on the master page. How can I accomplish this? Thanks....

Comment: Then the content page can access it's master to set the text but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below code in your `MasterPage`:

```
HiddenField hid1 = (HiddenField)MainContent.FindControl("hid1");
if (hid1 != null)
{
     Label1.Text = hid1.Value;
}
```

**EDIT:** Make sure your `Label` on the `MasterPage` is outside your `ContentPlaceHolder`, as I made this mistake when I first tested.

The above code should work as provided, with your control names, I'm not sure why you are using:

`.FindControl("MainContent_hid1");`

instead of

`.FindControl("hid1");`

Comment: This is what I tried, but hid1 keeps coming up null. See the updated edits how my page looks now. Can't figure out why it's not finding the control.....

Comment: I've edited answer, I think it will be Label1 that is coming up null as I tested and had same issue before posting.

Comment: No, that's not the case... During debugging, hid1 comes up null. Hence, it doesn't set Label1 to a value... Don't know what to do... I'm stumped... this should work... The Label is outside the ContentPlaceHolder.

Comment: and you've tried it with: .FindControl("hid1") rather than .FindControl("MainContent_hid1")?

Comment: Got it! After debugging and looking at the Controls collection, I saw that the name of the control was "hid1" instead of "MainContent_hid1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

There can be multiple `conterntPlaceHolder` on your master page.
use the id which contains your `hidden field` in this case I assume that it is `ContentPlaceHolder1`

```
   HiddenField hid1 = (HiddenField)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hdnRptTitle");
   if (hid1 != null)
   {
     Label1.Text = hid1.Value;
   }
```

There is a similar post on `so`

[How to access content page controls from master page in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979669/how-to-access-content-page-controls-from-master-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: may be it is like him but I got from the answer from the link which I provided in my answer.

Comment: Sheknar, thanks. I implemented, but the control comes up null. My hidden field is inside a Maincontent placeholder. I will edit my code to let you see what I have, and please evaluate and let me know what might be wrong... Thanks so much...

Comment: Got it! After debugging and looking at the Controls collection, I saw that the name of the control was "hid1" instead of "MainContent_hid1

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that you can access a control in a content-page of a master-page? A `MasterPage` is used for multiple pages, why do you want to hardlink it with a specific page, it won't work anymore without it. If the `HiddenField` is essential for the operation of the master you should declare it there.

> For every child page, there is a different rpt title which needs to
>   show up on the master page. How can I accomplish this?

Then the content page can access it's master to set the text but not vice-versa.

You could provide a public property in the master, e.g.:

```
public string ReportTitle
{
    get { return this.LblReportTitle.Text; }
    set { this.LblReportTitle.Text = value; }
}
```

and in the `ContentPage`, for example in it's `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // assuming the type of your master is SiteMaster
    var master = this.Master as SiteMaster;
    if (master != null)
        master.ReportTitle = hdnRptTitle.Value;
}
```

This approach is still linking the master with one (or multiple) of it's childs, but it would still "work" if the content-page would use a different master-type. You'd also be informed with a compiler error if somebody  remove or change the property.

However, where the content stores the report-type or where the master displays it is an implementation detail and can be changed in future without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a master page and get the control like this:

VB.Net:

```
Dim te As HiddenField
Dim val As String

te = Me.Page.Master.FindControl("hdnRptTitle")
val = te.Value
```

c#:

```
HiddenField te = default(HiddenField);
string val = null;

te = this.Page.Master.FindControl("hdnRptTitle");
val = te.Value;
```

Comment: I think he wants it opposite. (I know the question title is confusing)