# Accessing text boxes in a web control on a master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to access multiple textboxes on a master page. The textboxes are declared in a separate web control and it won't let me call the names of the textboxes so I can populate them with data. I have multiple textboxes like I said, but for example, when I try to write to `txtName` it will not let me even though when I click on the Design View it says it is there.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access master page control from content page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page)

Comment: @Paddy OP explained exactly opposite of that link. Its not duplicate of that. `"The textboxes are declared in a separate web control"`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj - I'm not sure you're right, but even so, there is an answer here that shows how to access content page from the master page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979669/how-to-access-content-page-controls-from-master-page-in-asp-net?rq=1 however, I'm not sure this is really recommended practice.

Comment: @Paddy Yes this question may be duplicate of your second comment link. I just said its not duplicate of the first comment.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Actually, it could be considered a duplicate of the first link also. The answer contained there is relevant to this question, although it is only part of the solution. It is definitely **not** "exactly opposite" like you stated.

Answer (score 2):

Expose the text boxes inside the web control as properties.

In webcontrol.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
```

In webcontrol.ascx.cs

```
public virtual TextBox TxtName { get {return txtName;} //note capitalization
```

Then do the same thing in the master page to expose the web control.

In masterpage.master

```
<uc1:MyWebControl runat="server" id="MyWebControl1" />
```

In mastermage.master.cs

```
public virtual MyWebControl myWebControl{get {return myWebControl1;}}
```

Then make your master page strongly typed from the content page by adding a [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directive.

In default.aspx

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="MyMasterPageClass" />
```

Then you can access it from your content page code behind. In default.aspx.cs

```
Master.myWebControl.TxtName.Text="Hello, world!";
```

The reason it's necessary to do this is that controls declared on .aspx, .ascx, and .master pages are `protected` instead of `public` and there's no way (as of right now) to change them that I'm aware of. So we can use properties to expose these controls as public.