# How to know if a content page contains a multiview from master page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page and I need to know if a content page has a multiview. If the content page has a multiview I need to know which view is selected. 
I know I can get this by using `ActiveViewIndex`. But first I need to know if the content page has a Multiview (because not all of the pages I load in the masterpage has multiview) and once I know if it has a multiview I need to access to that multiview to use the `ActiveViewIndex` property.

I have used this property from the content page like this:

```
void MultiView_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    string viewIndex = ((sender as MultiView).ActiveViewIndex).ToString();
    this.lblIndex.Text = viewIndex; 
}
```

But I need to use it from the `Page_Load` of the master page.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Master page should know nothing about actual page. If you break the model, then you make maintenance and system understanding harder.

Comment: Take a look at this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4979872/1036274).

Comment: I know maybe is not the best way to do it. Yesterday I had a look to the question/answer you say, but I can't use the FindControl because in each content page the Multiview is called different (Sometimes is "Multiview1" others is "MultiviewMovements", etc.). I need to access in a general way to the Multiview and once I access to it check which view is selected.